# calculate average of a column based on values of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

| count | A |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 4 |
| yes | 4 |
| yes | 5 |
| yes | 5 |

I want output like this that is I want to calculate mean when the column value of count is result, taking the mean of the previous values of A

| count | A |
| --- | --- |
| yes | 4 |
| yes | 4 |
| result | 4.0 |
| yes | 5 |
| yes | 5 |
| result | 5.0 |

I am not geting the result in pandas

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple extension of previous answer.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""count   A
yes 4
yes 4
yes 5
yes 5"""),sep="\t")

df = (df.fillna(-100)
 .groupby("A", as_index=False).apply(lambda dfa: dfa.append({"count":"result","A":dfa.A.mean()}, ignore_index=True))
 .replace({-100:np.nan})
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

|  | count | A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | yes | 4 |
| 1 | yes | 4 |
| 2 | result | 4 |
| 3 | yes | 5 |
| 4 | yes | 5 |
| 5 | result | 5 |